# JSON POST Request on the iPhone (Using HTTPS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ssl, https

I have a WCF service hosted and I'm trying to use it within an iPhone app as a JSON POST request. I plan on using the JSON serializer later, but this is what I have for the request:

```
    NSString *jsonRequest = @"{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"letmein\"}";
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mydomain.com/Method/"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];
```

In my data received I'm just printing it to the console:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSMutableData *d = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    [d appendData:data];

    NSString *a = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Data: %@", a);
}
```

And within this response I get this message:

```
Data: ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>
        <!-- I've took this out as there's lots of it and it's not relevant! -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p xmlns="">The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="https://mydomain.com/Method/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this happens and where I'm going wrong?

I've read about using [ASIHTTPPost](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) instead but I can't get the demo to run in iOS4 :(

Thanks

EDIT:

I've just used to [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to sniff out what's happening when I call from the iPhone (Simulator) and this is what it gave me:
[image]

<strike>The only thing strange I've noticed is it says "SSL Proxying not enabled for this host: enable in Proxy Settings, SSL locations". Does anyone know what this means?</strike> (This also happens in my working windows client).

I've just ran this on my windows client and the only thing that is different is the Request and Response text which is encrypted. Am I missing something in order to use a secure HTTP connection to do this?

NEW EDIT:
This works with a non-HTTPS request such as:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=UK&sensor=true. So I guess the problem is getting the iPhone to send the POST properly over SSL?

I am also using these methods:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]
        forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    if([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

This allows me to get this far. If I don't use them I get an error sent back saying:

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “mydomain.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.

Comment: Can you see the logs in your server if they have anything interesting in them?

Comment: I don't have access to them right now. I know that the service is setup and working with other clients though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FIXED!

Changed:

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

to:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

You also need these two methods:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]
        forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    if([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, didn't you forget to "return NO;" in the last line of the last method?

Comment: I'm not sure, I return YES to a void method. Can't remember why now.

Comment: @ing0 can you translate this line into swift plz [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: @QadirHussain Sorry I haven't written much swift. Check out this answer though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24321320/143979

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Objective C at all, but try setting the Accept header to `application/json` instead of `application/jsonrequest`.

Comment: Tried that earlier. Should it be like this anyway? Just did it again and I still get the same response! :(

Comment: `application/json` is definitely the correct MIME type for JSON data.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type

Comment: Are you sure that your web service accepts data in url-encoded format and responds in json format? It will be easy to figure out the issue, if you execute a curl command and program the same in obj-C

Comment: would be helpful also if you posted the source and particularly config for your WCF service.  Also, have you tried visiting the service help page that's in the error message?

Comment: Unfortunatly I didn't write the service. I have a .NET app doing exactly what I want using a similar process. So I know it's not a server issue!

Comment: well then, get a tool like Fiddler, and compare what your .NET app and your iPhone app are sending over the wire - request headers and content - and if the iPhone app isn't the same then you have an idea where to look next.

Comment: Btw, I did visit the service help page. It's just a dump of what I should expect in XML and in JSON.

Comment: The comparisons are the same except for the encrypted request and response texts... :(

Answer (score 0):

change

```
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];
```

to

```
NSData *requestData = [jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

dic is NSMutable Dictionary with object and keys.
baseUrl is your server webservice url.

```
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSString *encodedString = [jsonString base64EncodedString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@wsName",baseUrl]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:encodedString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data"];
```