# Pass value to webservice usng POST method

Tags: ios, json, post

I need to pass the username and password to a url using post method.Also I want to get the response back from the service.can anybody please tell the efficient way to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? a simple form should do... without more information (especially info on what you tried already) it's impossible to help

Answer (score 1):

[data not post through webservice json in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097092/data-not-post-through-webservice-json-in-ios/16098018#16098018)

Check out this link for the answer posted by me in regards to the question same as that of your question. Hope it will help you .

Answer (score 1):

add this code on .h file

```
@interface xyz
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableData *receivedData;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;
```

add this code on .m file 
@implementation........

```
@synthesize receivedData,connection;
-(void)requesttoserver
{

    //if there is a connection going on just cancel it.
    [self.connection cancel];

    //initialize new mutable data
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData = data;


    //initialize url that is going to be fetched.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.your urlname"];

    //initialize a request from url
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

    //set http method
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //initialize a post data

    NSString *postData = @"username password";


    //set request content type we MUST set this value.


    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type" ];

    //set post data of request
    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //initialize a connection from request
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    self.connection = connection;
    //[connection release];

    //start the connection
    [connection start];


}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"error%@" , error);
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];





}
```

call to `requesttoserver` method when you want to post data

Comment: @Shan try this and tell me the result

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one

```
NSString *Post=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&password_confirmation=%@",[textfieldArray objectAtIndex:0],[textfieldArray objectAtIndex:1],[textfieldArray objectAtIndex:2]];

NSData *PostData = [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *PostLengh=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[Post length]];
NSURL *Url=[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://offers2win.com/api/v1/users/"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:Url     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:PostLengh forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Lenght"];
[request setHTTPBody:PostData];

NSData *ReturnData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:Nil error:Nil];

NSString *Response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:ReturnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Response = [Response stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSLog(@"Response%@",Response);
```

Comment: If this is attempted code please add it in your question and not as an answer. If this code is a solution please mark this as accepted answer.