# Parse Google Calendar JSON in SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-calendar-api

I'm brand new to Swift development.  I'm trying to build a basic app which will read a feed from Google Calendar which is returned in JSON.

I am able to use a NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest call as described in this thread: [Make REST API call in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321165/make-rest-api-call-in-swift) and I get a result of some sorts.

My problem is I am unable to parse the JSON into some meaningful objects from which I can create a list of upcoming events.

My code this far is:

```
var url : String = "some url"
var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
    let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

    if (jsonResult != nil){
      // No idea how to parse this object as it seems to be a NSDictionary but battling to interact with it.
    }
    else 
    {

    }
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not use Calendar GData feeds. GData shutdown date is Nov 17th this year. Take a look into the v3 version instead: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that - very helpful.. I did not know they were ending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint after

```
let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary
```

then you'll be able to see the dictionary key/value pairs.  I copied/pasted your code and see this:

[image: Debugger]

You can access the values by using `jsonResult.objectForKey("keyName")`.   I'm also going to downcast using `as DataType`.

Example)

```
let encoding = jsonResult.objectForKey("encoding") as String
let version = jsonResult.objectForKey("version") as String
let feed = jsonResult.objectForKey("feed") as NSDictionary
```

Comment: jsonResult.objectForKey("keyName") was they key here for me and what I was missing.  I found that I was trying to read the objects in an incorrect way.