# How do I know what kind of error occurred in Swift

Tags: swift, try-catch

Further to [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46895243/111307). For me, an error occurs when using this code. I want to know exactly what kind of error occurs from the catch block. You're supposed to do this [by catching the error's type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html#ID541), but I don't see error types enumerated in the [jsonObject documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject)

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    print(json)
} catch {
    print("error") //which error?
}
```

Is there a way to do this in swift, or how can I find the exceptions an object throws?

Comment: Swift automatically gives you an error object as input to the `catch` clause so do `print(error)` to get a proper error message (the error handling in the linked answer is really bad)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Wow! Magic -- shouldn't that cause a compiler error?

Comment: Like I said it is given to you (synthesised) so it exists without having to be declared

Comment: Not related to your question but `[String: AnyObject]` is the dictionary format prior to Swift 3. It should be `[String: Any]`

Answer (score 2):

In the catch section the error is available for you, so instead of the string your are printing right now, you can access the [error object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error):

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    print(json)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: It works! But `error` wasn't declared anywhere, so how?

Comment: It is the way the `catch` block is working. It automatically gives you the error which was thrown.

Comment: Do not use *Or a bit shorted version of the error* (`.localizedDescription`) with `JSONSerialization` and `JSONDecoder`. Instead of the real error you get a generic meaningless message

Comment: @vadian agree. Edited my answer